# response.redirect is not working in google chrome. redirecting to google page

Tags: c#, asp.net

after successful login . page should redirect to home page, but its redirecting to Google.com only in Google chrome . how to stop redirecting to Google.com

in Mozilla working fine.not working in Google Chrome browser
how to resolve this issue?

Tried all 3 not redirecting to home.aspx

```
    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    Response.Redirect("http://Home.aspx");
```

Comment: try removing `~`and `/` sign and check.

Comment: Third is totally wrong

Comment: i tried that but not worked. same result. @nadeem. but when i tried that removing ~/ in some of the google chrome browsers it worked but not all .@nadeem

Comment: @krishnamohan You meant : Sometimes work and sometimes not work?

Comment: no never works for some crome browsers..but in some chrome browsers working@nelek

Comment: @krishnamohan: What is your `version` of chrome.is it _updated_ or not ?

Comment: Version 43.0.2357.134 m
 
Google Chrome is up to date.@nadeem

Comment: `Redirect` work fine even in `ver.30` when I last time used chrome... so... (??)

Comment: i think you should reset chrome try this link https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en

Comment: @krishnamohan: It should work as, the version is upto date. as it is working on my side. Otherwise you can use some other way to _redirect_ it

Comment: i did reset ..not worked @manish

Comment: is it on `button_click` ?? or after some _event_ you want this _redirection_ to call ??

Comment: after login button. im redirecting to home.aspx.@nadeem

Comment: @krishnamohan: can you show some more code relevant to this ?

Comment: May be its cache issue. Clear cache and history in crome browser then check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if any where you might have used this line in button event/control and remove that .

```
OnClientClick="javascript:history.go(-1)"
```

Comment: Thanks somebody used that js in button control in my application. so it was redirecting to previous page/google page.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, if you only want to redirect the user *after successful login*, you can do in some other way.

**Assuming that you want to redirect it on `Button_Click`** So here you go

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your Code Here //
        string RedirPageUrl = "Home.aspx";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "window.location.href = '" + RedirPageUrl + "';", true);
    }
```

Not tested, but it should work fine.

Comment: ) is expected..@nadeem

Comment: @krishnamohan: Updated it, check now